# Can I restore one of my user's profiles in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, user-profiles

My youngest daughter uses my 4 year old laptop, which has Windows Vista installed.  Somehow she got some Trojan (Vista Internet Security).  (I'd love to know how that happened, seeing as how she is a standard user, and I have VIPRE as my AV.)  Anyway, I ran a deep anti-virus scan using VIPRE, which identified it.  I decided to delete everything that it identified.  Now she cannot use anything in her profile.  If she tries to bring up the browser, it recycles over and over again a dialog box asking which program to use.  If I try to run any program at all, it doesn't know what to do.  For example, it is totally lost trying to run the command line.  If I bring up Windows Explorer and navigate to Windows\System32 and try to run the command line, or anything at all from there, it goes "Huh?"

What in heck has happened?? Is it possible to fix this, and if so, how?

As an aside, I can log into my account (my account on that machine is an administrator) and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to just create a new account and just import the good files in the C:/Users/(username)/ folder to the new account, and then delete the original. Right now the situation just seems too messy to fix...

Comment: I think I'l try this.

Comment: any success? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try a system restore, or if you've created a backup you should be able to copy that back over. If not then just delete the user and recreate it.